# How can I connect my macOS to docker network minikube?

Tags: network, docker

I run the minikube on my macos, and minikube container use the minikube network, check below:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME       DRIVER    SCOPE
906776761e62   bridge     bridge    local
89afa32d0810   host       host      local
b7cc12043647   minikube   bridge    local
4f7dca22f5b6   none       null      local
```

```
$ docker network inspect b7cc12043647
[
    {
        "Name": "minikube",
        "Id": "b7cc120436478e8be737a60df8fd0147e46ad09ccfbea41e564aaebff0f5ee27",
        "Created": "2021-09-28T09:57:59.40193434Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.49.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.49.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "a35d5e4b87e1bc2a747a8e1902c8bd9363d9ec1f1baf2424671d1a3a497f18ff": {
                "Name": "minikube",
                "EndpointID": "97d5f2ccc7a306f56200a0a6811f90db8e6cb0f8269762041797b2e9c25a1d63",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:31:02",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.49.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "--icc": "",
            "--ip-masq": "",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io": "true"
        }
    }
]
```

and I also know docker on macos is running in Docker Desktop(linux VM), but now how can I use macos bridge connect to the linux VM?

---

For that purpose, I have created a bridge named `bridge1` on my macos.

Comment: Does https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/ help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a macOS network bridge to connect to the Linux VM. Creating `bridge1` bridge interface on the macOS side won't connect you in any way to the bridged network interfaces inside Docker, as they're running totally separate.

Comment: because I want to access the minikube dashboard from macos. that's the purpose.