# Does macOS have network namespaces like Linux?

Tags: network

Does macOS have [network namespaces](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/network_namespaces.7.html) like Linux?

Linux uses `ip netns` to manage the network namespaces, but what about macOS?

---

**EDIT-01**

I want to access the minikube vm from macos.
https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/how-can-i-connect-my-macos-to-docker-network-minikube/17813

---

**EDIT-02**

Before ask this question, I have tried minikube tunnel [minikube tunnel](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/starting-tunnel-for-service-dashboard-ingress-take-a-long-time-without-response/17763/10)

Comment: Which practical problem do you want to solve with this?

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: You already have https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429075/how-can-i-connect-my-macos-to-docker-network-minikube as a question, isn't this the same then?

Comment: @nohillside I want to find a way to manage the network namespace, I think they are not equal.

Comment: It might make more sense to focus on the practical question you have (how to connect to docker), because the solution will be different from whatever works in the Linux world (and no, macOS doesn't know about network namespaces).

Comment: macOS is derived from xBSD OS, and thus has more in common with it, than Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, macOS does not have network namespaces like Linux. You will not find a set of functionality in the macOS kernel that works 1:1 like the Linux network namespace featureset.

Regarding accessing the minikube vm from macOS, you're basically "holding it the wrong way". You seem to be leaving out what you have actually tried, which makes it very hard to help you there. You have probably attempted something like the official docs described, but made some minor mistake that stopped it from working) - and now you're chasing ideas in odd directions instead of focusing on why the intended way didn't work.

I'll recommend going back to the docs and follow the instructions, and then ask here again when the instructions fail to work. I.e. use the provided tunnel feature.

Comment: before ask this question, I have tried use minikube tunnel, check my post edit-02.